# Find which account owns a Google Cloud Project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

Is there a way to find the account owner for an existing GCP project?

I manage a number of google accounts. I'm trying to create a new Google Cloud project and the id I want is "already taken".

The goal here is to add Firebase analytics to an older android app, to replace the deprecated Google Analytics for Android SDK. So it's entirely possible I created a GCP project for it years ago and I'm trying to figure if it's already registered under one of the accounts I manage, without having to log in in the console with each account one by one.

Comment: You can list the member accounts for any project that you have AIM roles to access the project. You can then see who are Project Owners. There are no APIs or public access method to obtain information on any projects without the correct IAM roles. Note: If you created the project years ago, you would have had bills on your credit card. If you did not pay those bills, the project would have been deleted. If you did pay those bills, collect the information and contact Google Billing support.

Answer (score 1):

I'm 99.9% certain that functionality doesn't exist... at least not exposed to us end-users.

Maybe one of the official Google employees on here will chime in and prove me wrong... but I think your only alternative would be to reach out to GCP support directly. If you can prove you manage X, Y, & Z accounts, they could probably confirm/deny which account has ownership... but I suspect it'll be easier for you to log in yourself, as you've already suggested.